# Bash script fails on creating directory in WebDAV

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, webdav

For my VPS I've created a bash script what will run every three hours by a cronjob for backing-up my VPS. All databases (in this case) will be dumpt and moved to a new folder on a storage-services connected via WebDAV.

It runs perfectly until yesterday. The script gives me the error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/stack/VPS-Backups/Srv1/Database/07-10-2016_12:00’: No such file or directory

The script (where it goes wrong):

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_BACKUP="/stack/VPS-Backups/Srv1/Database/`date +%d-%m-%Y`_`date +%H:%M`"

# Create the backup directory
mkdir $DB_BACKUP
```

I checked/procees the following things already:

- Re-mount the WebDAV
- Check if the directory structure "/stack/VPS-Backups/Srv1/Database" exist
- The URL/username/password of the WebDAV doesn't changed
- The supplier of the storage storage doesn't changed a thing

What can I do? Thanks for helping! :-)

Comment: Are you sure this is the script? I see a `~` in front of the path where it's failing.

Comment: Sorry, my fault; typo. Fixed it :)

Comment: In this context, the plain reading of "No such file or directory" is that the parent directory does *not* in fact exist. Extraordinary claims, extraordinary evidence, &c.

Comment: Why don't you modify your script to `cd /stack/VPS-Backups/Srv1/Database || exit` as one step, and `mkdir "$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M)"` as a second, so we can see which of those two operations fails? (No need to have two separate `date` calls; better to consolidate not just for efficiency but also to guard against bugs -- if you were calling this script right at midnight and one `date` ended up on the other side of the margin from the other, that could be embarrassing).

Comment: It looks like it goes wrong at making the directory: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘07-10-2016_12:27’: No such file or directory`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Any other ideas?

Comment: Try changing the time format to remove the colon -- those are reserved on some filesystems.

Comment: I'd also suggest some general experimentation. Does `mkdir foo` work? You may have a more general issue that needs to be investigated on the server side.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `mkdir foo` works!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thats it! The colon was the problem. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad to hear; I'll add an appropriate answer.

Comment: btw, `%d-%m-%Y` is a very poorly chosen date format. If you have any control over it, consider using `%Y%m%d` instead -- that way your dates' ASCII sort order matches their logical sort order.

Comment: And a single `date` invocation should suffice; you can pass in arbitrary string fragments in the format string (though of course, a literal `%` needs to be mangled by doubling it; and you'll want to quote the whole thing if it contains any shell metacharacters).

Comment: @tripleee, *nod* -- I pointed that out in the second comment on the question (particularly including the ability for two separate date calls to return inconsistent results should this script be run overlapping midnight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
dirname=$(date '+%Y%m%dT%H%M') # subset of an ISO 8601 date (only missing %S)
cd /stack/VPS-Backups/Srv1/Database || exit
mkdir -- "$dirname"
```

The notable changes encapsulated here:

- Break out the `cd` from the `mkdir`, to clarify which of these operations is failing.
- Remove characters that aren't guaranteed by POSIX to be valid in filenames (the [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276)). In practice, this means the colons need to go.

Also, this follows [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) guidelines for the date format. This means other software will be able to parse your directory names as dates out-of-the-box. Using YYYYMMDD also prevents confusion between MMDDYYYY and DDMMYYYY, and makes your names' ASCII sort order match their logical sort order, so you can use standard UNIX tools for range selection.